# Замыкания. Обратный отсчет в консоли

Tags: javascript

```
for (let countdown = 5; countdown > 0; countdown--) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(countdown);
  }, 1000 * countdown);
}
console.log("поехали");
```

Как переделать код чтобы выводило вот так:

```
   5 //пауза 1 секунда
   4 //пауза 1 секунда
   3 //пауза 1 секунда
   2 //пауза 1 секунда
   1 //пауза 1 секунда
   "поехали!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут отлично подойдет async/await

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
  for (let countdown = 5; countdown > 0; countdown--) {
    console.log(countdown);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
  console.log("поехали");
})();
```

Или вот такой вариант и с таймаутом:

```js
const messages = [
  5, 4, 3, 2, 1, "поехали"
];

for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(messages[i]);
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```